# Detect missing binary symbols in Linux repository

Tags: linux, rpm, deb

Is there any tool that is able to validate that a linux repository contains all needed binary symbols? I need to verify completeness of the repository over binary symbols.

I.e. I need to know that for every executable file in the repository all its external symbols (as reported by `nm -g`) are provided by some shared library from this repository.

As for now my target repository is not restricted to rpm or deb, or any particular distribution at all, I just need to know is there any such tool at all?

I was unsuccessful googling for that, so I'll be grateful for at least key words for google.

Comment: In case anyone is also interested, I've written a tool for ROSA Linux (it's distro- and package- independent).

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/repochecker_binsym/0.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALT linux has implemented something called set:versions as
a type of dependency,

The set:versions is a compact symbol encoding that can do
subsetting efficiently. What that means is that an executable
which uses only some of the symbols in libraries has a set:version
that can detect if it is a proper subset, i.e. no missing symbols.

The set:version implementation was written by Alexey Tourbin.

Meanwhile, its not too hard to use nm(1) to generate lists of
all provided library symbols, and all needed executable symbols.

If you use a common file format for provided/required symbols, and
alphabetize and remove duplicates using "sort -u", then you can
simply diff the two files to ensure that there are no unresolved symbols.